# Python cant access all of cookies that are appearing in Chrome inspector

Tags: javascript, python, cookies

I created the cookies using JavaScript, the page is then reloaded and I retrieve the cookies with Python, but the only cookie that is retrieved is the session cookie.

Adding Cookie:

```
 function changeFeatures() {
        document.cookie = "byteName=" + document.getElementById("byteName").value+"; path=/";
        document.cookie = "byteDescription=" + document.getElementById("byteDescription").value+"; path=/";
        document.cookie = "byteType=" + document.getElementById("byteType").value+"; path=/";
        document.cookie = "byteEndian=" + document.getElementById("byteEndian").value+"; path=/";
        document.cookie = "byteParent=" + document.getElementById("byteParent").value+"; path=/";
        document.cookie = "byteOffset=" + document.getElementById("byteOffset").value+"; path=/";
        document.cookie = "byteLength=" + document.getElementById("byteLength").value+"; path=/";

        location.reload();
    }
```

Retrieving Cookie:

```
 import requests
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/)
    print(r)
    c = r.cookies
    print(c)
    i = c.items()
    print(i)
```

r prints:

> Response [200]

c prints:

> RequestsCookieJar[]

i prints:

> [('session', 'eyJfZmxhc2hlcyI6W3siIHQiOlsibWVzc2FnZSIsIlBsZWFzZSBsb2cgaW4gdG8gYWNjZXNzIHRoaXMgcGFnZS4iXX1dLCJfZnJlc2giOmZhbHNlfQ.XJEbzA.2QOTc9iPNBD_RSEVgAdnvR36chE')]

Picture of Chrome cookies
[image]

Comment: The JavaScript doesn't run when you use `requests`, it only gets cookies that are actually set by the server on the response.

Comment: I am confused by your answer. The JavaScript is ran because the cookies are apparent in the chrome inspector. If the JavaScript wasn't ran, than there would not be any cookie that has the word "byte" at the beginning of it.

Comment: Why would that have any bearing on it? They're *only* set in the browser, client-side. Python makes a separate request to the *server*. What are you actually trying to *achieve* here?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the cookies that have the word "byte" in their name using Python. Sorry should have clarified.

Comment: That's clear. It's unclear what problem you're actually trying to solve by setting random cookies in the browser, or by accessing them from Python.

Comment: Right, but cookies are client-side. They only exist _in_ your browser. This is probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't know if this is the best explanation but I am trying to pass a list of strings (each as a cookie) when a button is pressed. The page then refreshes, and a table within the page is modified based on those strings that were passed in. I do not want to use the URL to pass in these strings as URL parameters for other reasons.

Comment: So what exactly are you hoping to do with `requests` here? It seems like you're trying to build an SPA with all of the state in separate cookies, which seems... unwise.

Comment: ...so why are you trying to load them with `requests`? Do you need those strings server-side? You can work with them client-side using JavaScript from the cookies you already have, but if you need them on the server you should be sending them there. If you don't want to use URL parameters you can POST them.

Comment: I figured it out. I was supposed to use request.cookie in python to retrieve the cookie since I'm using Flask.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was supposed to use `request.cookie` in python to retrieve the cookie since I'm using Flask.